# What is the difference in Indexable Types and Arrays in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning Typescript, and I have came to the point as Indexable Types where I presented with the example as:

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;
}
let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];

let myStr: string = myArray[0];
```

out put is : Bob

As we can declare the type array as:

```
let myArray:string[];
myArray = ["Bob","Fred"];
console.log(myArray[0]);
```

out put is : Bob

so my question is what is the difference in these both approaches? and where can we use such Indexable Types instead of arrays?

Comment: @KiranShahi Sorry not a duplicate, that explains the difference between the two syntaxes for defining arrays, this is the difference between an indexable type and an array

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir ok :)

Answer (score 5):

Any object in JavaScript is indexable, the difference is what else you are getting.

The `StringArray` interface defines any object that can be indexed by a `number` and has all values of type string. Sure this can be an array, but it can be any other object that satisfies this constraint. Ex:

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;
}
let o : StringArray = {
    0: "A", //ok
    // "V" : "B" // error
    // 1: 0  error
}
let arr : Array<string> = o; // Error
console.log(o instanceof Array) // false
```

`o` satisfies `StringArray` but is not an true `Array`, as it does not have all the methods of an array (and thus assignment to `arr` fails), and even if it did it was not created using the array literal syntax (`[]`) or `new Array` so it is not an instance of an `Array`(thus `o instanceof Array` returns false).

`string[]` (and equivalently `Array<string>`) on the other hand  models a true JavaScript array.